# Hermite interpolation polynom in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, hermite

Anyone know where i find the Hermite interpolation algorithm in MATLAB. Which Hermite interpolation algorithm solve this?

I need to calculate a polynom. Example (just example):

```
x=[1,2,3];

y=[0.5,1,12]

y'=[1,0.2,0.9]

y''=[0.1,0.6,0.8]

x2=[1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5];

polynom=hermit_interpolation(x,y,y',y'',x2); % i need the polynom to

y2=polyval(polynom,x2);

plot(x2,y2);
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `pchip()`, which is documented nicely with examples at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pchip.html.

Comment: But the pchip() can be configured to work with second, third derivative y',y'',y'''

Comment: I think the pchip can't work with second ord third derivative.

Comment: y' is calculated internally, and kept the same. To keep y' and y'' the same, see `spline()` like the above techdoc suggests.